# Dynamically Added Controls End Up Wrapped in a Generic Type?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, inheritance

I'm writing a formbuilder for our CMS which dynamically loads bespoke controls into panels within a repeater.

The bespoke controls all inherit from, lets say 5arx.FormBuilder.FormControl, a base class which defines abstract methods for initialising, validating, repopulating, gathering submitted data from them. Controls range from simple text fields to complex, composite client-side controls.

It all works very well, but I've noticed something I feel is anomalous. During the course of writing code to retrieve form controls. gather their data and persist it to my database I noticed that their type reverts to the way objects get typed if you write your code in the (v. irritating) VS 'website project' mode.

So, for example a control that is defined as living in a namespace and being of type

<strike>`5arx.FormBuilder.FormControl.MyBespokeControl`</strike>
    Sarx.FormBuilder.FormControl.MyBespokeControl

at runtime reports its type (via simple call to GetType()) as being of type:

<strike>`ASP.5arx_FormBuilder_FormControl_MyBespokeControl`</strike>
    ASP.Sarx_FormBuilder_FormControl_MyBespokeControl

Getting the BaseType property will correctly retrieve the underlying class, but it is perplexing to me why this should be happening. Particularly as I spent much of the summer refactoring our app from its original form as VS Website project (complete with shared code in the App_Code folder and other nastiness) to the (IHMO) correct web application project + supporting claass libraries so that we would have control over our namespaces and not get everything compiled into the ASP.x namespace :-(

I would really appreciate some explanation/clarity.

EDIT: Modified the (hypothetical) example root namespace.

Comment: @Will - why did you delete the exchanges that followed this? Not so much moderation as censorship. I request the content be reinstated.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - you've taken much trouble to castrate this question but omitted to excise the offending sentence. 

>Let's say '5arx.

Comment: @5arx: No trouble at all. I don't know what you mean by offending sentence - sounds like there was a heated discussion before I got here. If you want to remove it, just edit your question.

Comment: @5arx A pleasant attitude works wonders around here when it comes to getting help from strangers

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - there *was* a weird sort of exchange about my question which continued long after the omniscient Jon Skeet + Google answered it. I was hoping it would stay on as some kind of exemplar re: the way stackoverflow operates and indeed the idiosyncrasies of the community in general.

Sadly as @Will has taken a hatchet to it, future generations of StackOverflowers won't be able to enjoy the thread - is there any way of rolling back the edit so I can at least keep a copy of the content for my personal enjoyment?

@ShaggyFrog - I don't recall unpleasantness - just a debate ...

Comment: PS. The guidelines re: Editing the posts of others clearly state 

"always respect the original author" - I'm not sure this has been the case here.

Comment: @5arx - The content and intention of your original question has been respected.  The inflammatory language that you keep bringing back adds no value to the question.  If you have a problem with the way people are responding to your questions, bring it to Meta, not here.

Comment: @BradLarson I don't object to the editing of the original question, but the wholesale removal of associated comments is just censorship. 

A wise and decent man (possibly attributable to Voltaire) once said something along the lines of  
  
"I may not agree with what you say but I will defend to the death your right to say it"


I expect better from a StackExchange site and a community of developers. Some of us are, *as we type* engaged in pro-democratic hacking activities. Others are on here snipping away perfectly valid contributions like little Nazis.

Comment: @5arx: you'll do much, *much* better here if you can manage to avoid comparing your fellow developers to a homicidal totalitarian regime.

Comment: I think that's good advice *wherever* one might be :-D

I'm making a point about censorship - some seem keen to remove all traces of personality from what is supposed to be a democratic community all have an equal right to express ideas and opinions (obviously within the bounds of legal, moral/other constraints) in the knowledge that these will remain as part of the wiki.

I'm not preaching race-hate or misogyny, nor advocating violence of any sort. Neither did any of the contributors to this thread, yet the entire comment history was deleted.

That just sucks, as does book-burning.

Comment: @5arx Looking through the edit history, I have no idea why you keep referring to such strongly emotional concepts like *censorship* and *book burning* and whatever else. Your comments were meant to be inflammatory, and they succeeded. But the system also worked the other way: other users were able to delete them while keeping your question relatively intact. If you aren't able to handle this level of editorial control, you should consider not using this site.

Comment: The edit history won't show you the numerous perfect valid and actually rather entertaining comments that have been deleted wholesale. Hence my references to the 'strongly emotional concepts' which you find so unpalatable. Most of the comments weren't even mine but I'd still rather they stood.
  
I haven't been using SO or sister SExchange sites for very long but I like to think I have made a valid contribution in my time and look forward to making more. So please, don't suggest pinning a virtual yellow star on my lapels.

Comment: @5arx "So please, don't suggest pinning a virtual yellow star on my lapels" You are equating your "suffering" with that of an act of genocide. Besides invoking Godwin's Law, you've made yourself look like an ignoramus. All your comments have done in the last few days is made you look bad. Consider deleting this thread wholesale.

Comment: @ShaggyFrog 

You should not regard the employment of analogy and t degree of linguistic licence as an attempt to 'equate' anything with anything else. And, because at no point have I made any reference to 'suffering' anywhere I fail to see why you chose to put the word in quotation marks as you have done above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is to allow the ASPX files to be updated and recompiled independently of your code-behind. Basically the *actual* control/page type is derived from the type which you write in code.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163675.aspx) (from 2006 but still apparently relevant :) for a lot more details.

I can't say I know a lot about ASP.NET, but based on the article it looks like this is independent of whether or not it's a "website" project. My guess is that any time you've got a 
template-style XML file (aspx, ascx etc), the ASP.NET runtime compiler will do all of this for you.

Whether or not it will happen if you *precompile* the site, I don't know.

Comment: @5arx: It didn't take any actual *knowledge* at all. It took a Google search for "asp.net class generation asp namespace msdn" :)

Comment: Yes, it does it for precompiled as well.  Thats the "new" ASP.Net 2.0 compilation model.  I say new because it was updated from the old 1.1 model.  Basically your entire website gets compiled into a single assembly.  This was a radical change from the 1.1 compilation model.  I believe there is a command line switch that controls that in 2.0 as well - I don't recall off the top of my head but I do remember the CM guys adding that to our NANT scripts.